# How to loop over rows in tables in Entity Framework and add rows to another table

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How do I practice logic as below sample code?

First when I foreach Entity tables, I got problems to looping class to use.
Because Entity Tables are fixed, but I need it to dynamic by foreach.

```
//I get Entity's table method
//Default have 3 tables: TbOne, TbTwo, TbThree
EntitiesContext newDB = new EntitiesContext(connection_information);
//If I want to add a record will do this:
TbOne tbObj = new tbObj();
tbObj.Col1 = value1;
tbObj.Col2 = value2;
tbObj.Col3 = value3;
newDB.TbOne.Add(tbObj);
newDB.SaveAysnc();

//EntityTables is all tables in Entity
//Now I need to foreach 3 tables as above: TbOne, TbTwo, TbThree
//EntityTables is those 3 tables.
foreach(table in EntityTables)
{
    // idList will pass from function parameter
    var datasets = table.Where(x => x.id.Contain(idList));

    // table2 is another Entity's table, but the schema the same as table
    table2.AddRange(datasets);
}
```

How to practice logic as above.

Comment: Are you trying to invent audit/versioned tables?

Comment: No, I trying to copy data from Table to Mirror Table  by program process.

Comment: It seems like your code already does what you need. Can you explain what the problem is?

Comment: @developer-partners Thanks for your question. When I foreach Entity tables, I got problems to looping class to use.

Comment: @YangLi what problems? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @developer-partners Yes, I cannot get EntityTables in class array. I only can use [EntityTables.Table] to search table's information. How do I looping in EntityTables in class array?

Comment: @developer-partners I get [error CS1579 foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'EntityTables' because 'EntityTables' does not contain a public instance definition for 'GetEnumerator'] error.

Comment: @YangLi what's the data type of EntityTables? It seems like EntityTables does not implement IEnumerable interface that is why you are getting that error.

Comment: @developer-partners Thanks for your answer. The data type of EntityTables is Entity Framework defult Class, I use Framework's Context to get connection object to Add/Update/Delete. But this object seems not implement IEnumerable. How can I implement IEnumerable it??

Comment: @YangLi can you update your question with more info, so I can help you? Can you share how you get the EntityTables object?

Comment: @developer-partners Thank you, I already updated my question, and use sample to express how I get EntityTables object.